# Python string manipulation without comparison

Tags: python, string

I am trying to solve this problem: I have some symbols:

```
 list =["RBS-UK", "GOOG-US"]
```

Now I have to transform all the region occurrences of "UK" to "GB". I could have done this easily:

```
 new_list =[]
 for symbol in list :
    temp_list=symbol.split("-")
    if temp_list[1]=="UK":
         temp_list[1]="GB"
     new_list.append("-".join(temp_list))
```

But can I do this without the equality comparision?

I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
 some_dict={}
 new_list =[]
 for symbol in list :
    temp_list=symbol.split("-")
    temp_list[1]=some_dict(temp_list[1])  # So this dict returns GB if its UK else returns same value as it is 
    new_list.append("-".join(temp_list))
```

Is it possible to do this, or are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah! sure

```
ls =['RBS-UK','GOOG-US']
map(lambda x: x.replace('-UK', '-GB'), ls)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to redefine the offset. You can simply replace the string:

```
for symbol in list:
    symbol = symbol.replace('-UK','-GB')
```

If the string is encountered it will be replaced, otherwise it is left alone entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a lookup, for which a dictionary will work:

```
translations = {'UK':'GB'} # and so on
for symbol in lst:
    country_code = symbol.split('-')[1]
    translated = translations.get(country_code,country_code)
    new_list.append('{}-{}'.format(symbol.split('-')[0],translated))
```

The key line is:

```
translated = translations.get(country_code,country_code)
```

Dictionary have a method `get()` which will return `None` if the key is not found. We use this to avoid raising `KeyError`. `get()` takes an optional second parameter for a value to return other than `None` if the key is not found.

In the snippet above, we pass the country code to `get()`, and ask it to return the same country code if there isn't a translation available, otherwise return the translation.

The second line uses string formatting to reconstruct the original symbol with the translated code and appends it to your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sub` function from the `re` module useful for regular expression operations.

Here is a one-liner which produces the list you want:

```
import re
newlist = [re.sub('UK','GB', symbol) for symbol in list]
```

Comment: This would get out of hand once the number of replacements went up.

Comment: Yes, right! I think your solution is the best of all in here! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a `dict`, you could use the `dict.get` method, which accepts a default argument used when the key isn't found, and so `some_dict.get(x,x)` means "return the value associated with `x` if it exists, otherwise return `x`":

```
>>> some_dict = {"UK": "GB"}
>>> country = "UK"
>>> some_dict.get(country, country)
'GB'
>>> country = "CA"
>>> some_dict.get(country, country)
'CA'
```